# Alternatives for running SciPy on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, scipy

I need to run some statistical tests in my app, which needs functions from scipy.stats.  However I found Google App Engine doesn't trust SciPy. So is there any GAE supported libraries which can do some stats calculations e.g. generate random numbers, estimate CDF, run T-tests, check normality, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Python 2.7 runtime includes NumPy](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27). It's a scientific library that can help you in what you want to do.

**Numpy** is a language extension that defines the numerical array and matrix type and basic operations on them.

More info for NumPy [here](http://www.numpy.org/)

Btw:

> However I found Google App Engine doesn't trust SciPy.

I think should be:

> GAE only supports native python code

**Edit**

For random numbers you can use [Python's Random](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

For CDF http://pysclint.sourceforge.net/pycdf/ or http://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/ but I am not sure if they just contain native code. You can try if you like.

Also take a look here http://www.astro.cornell.edu/staff/loredo/statpy/

Another approach could be to have a home server running any python module you might please. Then use a [PULL QUEUE TO communicate via REST](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-pull) with your "home" server and process the calculations there.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Maybe I did not express myself effectively, is there any GAE supported libraries which can do some stats calculation e.g. generate random numbers, estimate CDF, check normality, etc.